# How to get the field name based on the field type?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to get the field name and do some operation on it based upon the field type.

Let's say, the model is:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    m1 = models.FileField(...)
    m2 = models.CharField(...)
    m3 = models.IntegerField(...)
```

I want to create a method which detects the fieldfield and deletes it.

I thought of using meta dictionary. This is the method I created:

```
from django.db.models.fields.files import FieldFile
def method_name(instance):
    for nm, cls in instance.__dict__.items():
        if type(cls) is FieldFile:
             instance.nm.delete()
```

The above method didnt work as the type for the filefield is 'str' rather than a filefield. I will appreciate any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use `_meta` for that (if instance is a Model instance)

```py
from django.db.models.fields.files import FileField
def method_name(instance):
    for field in instance._meta.fields:
        # field.name - this returns the field name
        if isinstance(field, FileField):
            # do something
```